# Have Ubuntu server prefetch and store mail for a Windows workstation?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, gateway, mta, prefetch

I'd like to have my Ubuntu server (that also acts as a file and webserver) pre-fetch my mail from varying mail-accounts and have my Windows workstation fetch it from this Ubuntu server, in stead of directly from my mail providers.

What would such a setup be called? Is Ubuntu in such a setup acting like an MTA, a mail-proxy, a mail-gateway, or are those all synonymous terms perhaps, or is it acting as something else maybe?

And what would be the bare minimum of tools I would need to set this up?

My goal is to have the Ubuntu server act as sort of a mail backup system, so that I can always refetch the mail from this server in case of a workstation failure for instance, without having to rely on keeping mail on my mail-providers' servers.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/)?

Comment: Looks promising. At a quick glance though, it seems to be able to forward it via SMTP, but I'd actually want my Windows workstation to fetch it (with Thunderbird) from my Ubuntu server after fetchmail has fetched and stored the mail. Is this possible with fetchmail as well? In other words: can it also act as a POP3 server perhaps (the name "fetchmail" seems to suggest it can't)? Cause, if possible, I'd preferably have a one-package solution for this 'problem'.

Comment: Yes it can, it has support for IMAP(S) and POP3(S)

Comment: Well, that's great; I guess that's all I need then. I'm gonna look into it a bit deeper and when I find it indeed does what I need: expect the checkmark. For now; have an upvote. :) Thanks!